# C Compiler okay with different arity in function pointer declaration

Tags: c, function, pointers, arity

I am new to C and am confused why the compiler is totally okay with the following code snippet where I am casting the `foo` function pointer to other function pointers with different *arities*. This means that a single `void *` parameter in a function pointer declaration can be cast to *any* number of parameters? Can some one please help me understand why this is no problem in C?

```c
// 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // function pointer declaration
    void *(*foo)(void *);
    // castings
    (int *(*)(int *, int *))foo;
    (int *(*)(float *, int *, char **))foo;
    (int *(*)(int, int))foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking it's Undefined Behavior ... *though it will work most of the time*; I would avoid such constructs. https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p9

Comment: With the cast _you_ tell the compiler "foo is actually this type". And the compiler thinks  "oh, if you say so". It is not required to make it work.

Comment: Actually cast is fine. The problem is calling a function via incompatible pointer type.